# How to add daily events in fullcalendar of Adam Shaw Jquery Plugin?

Tags: jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I am developing an application which needs the events to be set on daily basis , hourly basis , weekly event or on the particular day event.

I am using the fullcalendar plugin but I am not been able to set the events on daily basis.
Is there any ways to set the event on daily basis? If yes then How?

If not possible through the fullcalendar please suggest me some other jquery plugin.

Comment: Are you talking about recurring events? I don't understand your question correctly - if you are just trying to create an event, what issue are you facing? Or maybe post some code to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You mean set like Lunch M-F 1200-1300?
Events need to have dates, so you may want to use [events function](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/), and generate them from `start` by adding day offsets and setting the hours. Check arshaw's [xdate](http://arshaw.com/xdate/).

Comment: I want to create events which needs options like daily,weekdays,weekends or some specific days. That too with the option of setting the time too.

Comment: You may want to listen to dayClick callback, which gives the date+time; then pop a dialog where you select end time and whatever options you need. 
Then create individual events with [renderEvent](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/), or use an array, function, json feed, etc.

Comment: Can u please provide me an example to perform the thing?

Comment: Please show what you have attempted so far, or where are you stuck. Your requirements are still not quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do daily events by specifying the day of week.

```
{
    title: timecondition.name,
    start: moment(),
    end: moment(),
    color: '#' + timecondition.color,
    dow: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    allDay: false,
}
```